# Clone form with 2 datepickers

Tags: jquery, forms, datepicker

I am trying to clone a form with two different texfields with datepicker. I have being searching for answeres here but coulnd find anything like mine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {

 var num = $('.clonedInput').length;    
 var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
 var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

 newElem.find('#label_cl label').attr('for' , 'label_cl' + newNum);
 newElem.find('#input_cl input').attr('id' , 'input_cl' + newNum);

 newElem.find('#label_cls label').attr('for' , 'label_cls' + newNum);
 newElem.find('#input_cls input').attr('id' , 'input_cls' + newNum);

$('#input' + num).after(newElem);
$('#input_cl' + newNum ).datepicker;
$('#input_cls' + newNum ).datepicker;
```

Comment: when I clone these form fields as above, the datepicker only works on the first two fields, acctually the original ones, that werent cloned

Comment: On the new ones, datepicker doenst shows up

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Iam trying to clone two fields and then add datepicker, but when I clone initiate datepicker with the new id name + variable, inst working

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the new input with a datepicker too, change:

```
$('#input' + num).after(newElem);
```

to

```
newElem.insertAfter('#input' + num).datepicker;
```

Comment: acctually, this #input is the class for the div wich the fields are inside

Comment: @RenatoFerreira If you haven't even written your selectors correctly then you're really going to have to share your html.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you initialize datepicker plugin.

```
$('#input_cl' + newNum ).datepicker;
$('#input_cls' + newNum ).datepicker;
```

Change it to

```
$('#input_cl' + newNum ).datepicker();
$('#input_cls' + newNum ).datepicker();
```

You have to call `datepicker` plugin so that it will apply the necessary event handlers on the input element.